# Importing a JavaScript function into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, function, laravel-blade

I have a JavaScript file called '`test.js`' and in that file is this code snippet;

```
function functionTest() {
    console.log('this works');
}
```

I then import `test.js` into the head of my HTML inside a blade.php with;

```
<script type="module" src="/js/test.js"></script>
```

Finally, in the script tag in the body portion of my HTML, I call `functionTest` with

```
<script>
    functionTest()
</script>
```

However I never get a console.log. Instead, this error is thrown from my HTML;

> Uncaught ReferenceError: functionTest is not defined<

Answer (score 5):

Your `<script>` tag is importing the JS file as a module.

As such it must be treated as a module, e.g., you need to export something, and import it to use it in your main file.

If you just want to use it as-is, without module-ish work, remove the `type="module"` from the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

*Export your function:*

```
const functionTest = () => {
console.log('this works')};
```

export default functionTest;

Then you can import it as module.

Comment: lol. thanks. this was from years ago.

Comment: No problem, searched for something like this as a newbie and thought maybe someone else will find it useful. lol